# What type of 2.5" drive is this, is it ide?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pata

Trying find out what type of drive I have in my laptop.

Is just died and I'm keen to find out what sort it is ?

Heres a photo...

[image]

Comment: You'll need to remove the black edge connector (top in this picture) and the metal cover (back in this picture) and install them on your replacement drive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Judging by the product code `MK3021GAS`:

> Interface Type: DMA/ATA-100 (Ultra)

a.k.a `IDE`

Answer (score 18):

Although it is IDE, the edge connector you can see at the top of the drive isn't, it is probably an adapter to a specific computer (or other device).

I suspect its something like this:

> [http://www.amazon.com/Original-Foxconn-Dell-Drive-Connector/dp/B000MMFPQU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MMFPQU)

If you wiggle it a bit it will probably come free and show the usual IDE double row of pins below it. Watch you don't bend the pins doing that wiggling, or when putting it back!

Comment: I've found a pair of needle nose pliers are extremely effective in helping to remove these things.

Comment: I just use an expansion slot cover plate.  I always have those scattered around.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search (Google) usind HDD2181 brought up [these specs](http://www.digitaltrends.com/hard-drive-reviews/toshiba-hdd2181-30-gb-ata-100-hard-drive-review/specifications/) along with many other sites.

You are correct, it is an IDE drive, specifically an ATA-100 interface.

Comment: Please do not be rude or condescending in your answers.

Comment: @BBlake - Wasn't my intent. Merely wanted to show that a 10 second search could have gotten the answer.

Comment: @BBlake - This doesn't read as rude or condescending, more instructive.

Comment: Google may be my friend, but so is Super User. Sometimes SU is more focused/precise/accurate/informative.

Comment: @Dennis - While that's true, it seems to me that SU is better for questions that don't have easy answers from a Google search.  I'll admit that my perception of the intent of SU and all the related sites may be incorrect.

Comment: "Google is your friend" comes across to many people as condescending.  As if they are somehow not smart enough to have considered that option.  I have no problem with anything else, just that phrase.  If that were a response to my question, I would be mildly put off by it.